# heteroskedasticity test for VAR model

Tags: time-series, vector-autoregression

I have a quick question, possibly stupid one. Can someone explain to me what T, K, q, Omega means in this ARCH-ML formula? Is it K - number of parameters, T-number of observations, q - lag, Omega - covariance matrix of VAR model?

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Quite possibly, but impossible to answer without knowing the source (which, if it is a good one, should define its notation itself somewhere).